# Difficulties understanding nodejs modules in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda function running on nodejs. It simply calls a REST API and should return whatever the API call returns. I'm trying to make use of the node-fetch module. At first I used this:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

Which resulted in the following error: Must use import to load ES Module

So I changed it to use import like this:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

Which in turn resulted in the following error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

So next I added "type": "module" to the package.json in the main filetree.

[(Main filetree)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFt9q.png)

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "name": "aws_lambda",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

So now I get an error like this:   "errorMessage": "exports is not defined in ES module scope\nThis file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.",

Changing the file extension to .cjs brings me back to 'Cannot use import statement outside a module'

How is this so freakin difficult? What am I supposed to do? Thanks

Comment: Yes! Replacing the import statement with 'const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));' solved it although I have absolutely no clue why.  Thank you! Ready to bang my head on the next wall :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use require you need to use node-fetch v2 by running npm like this:

```
npm install node-fetch@2
```